# how to upgrade unsupported release when `apt-get update` fails

Tags: apt, upgrade

I need to upgrade my OS because Kubuntu 19.10 is apparently "end of life" and no longer allows updates.  The update instructions I find say `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`.  But `apt-get update` fails:

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease [43.0 kB]
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:11 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Hit:12 https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease
Ign:13 https://dl.bintray.com/stripe/stripe-cli-deb stable InRelease
Get:14 https://dl.bintray.com/stripe/stripe-cli-deb stable Release [1,840 B]
Get:15 https://dl.bintray.com/stripe/stripe-cli-deb stable Release.gpg [821 B]
Get:16 https://weechat.org/ubuntu eoan InRelease [3,997 B]
Get:17 https://dl.bintray.com/stripe/stripe-cli-deb stable/main amd64 Packages [6,036 B]
Get:18 https://weechat.org/ubuntu eoan/main Sources [3,891 B]
Get:19 https://weechat.org/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages [4,972 B]
Get:20 https://weechat.org/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages [4,960 B]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

On too many occasions I've had `apt` render my computer unusable.  So I'm not willing to try `apt-get dist-upgrade` given that `apt-get update` can't even run successfully.

I saw some hackish looking solution about running `sed` on `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it was also 10 years old (not trustworthy) so I didn't try it.

I can't install or update any software now.  And the first command in the upgrade in [upgrade instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiscoUpgrades/Kubuntu) fails.  I'm stuck.  How do I get unstuck?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   (note: the 'us.' mirrror applies only to supported releases; so must be removed)

Comment: Not necessarily.  That's the 10-year-old answer I was referring to.  It says "If you want to continue using an outdated release" but I do NOT want to continue using an outdated release.

Comment: You need to fully-upgrade your system (that link OR the official EOLUpgrades link I posted) let you achieve that.. then you should be able to *release-upgrade* normally as per the instructions issues on the *release notes* of Ubuntu 20.04 in the *Upgrading from 19.10* section.  Upgrades as expected to be performed before the release goes EOL, or very shortly thereafter (ie. before the move to `old-release` occurs as that complicates things).  Your alternative is *upgrade via re-install*.

Comment: Ok that looks EOL Upgrade link looks like a viable solution.  Thanks!

Comment: The release notes I was referring to are https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes   Kubuntu have their own of course, but they're more about the Kubuntu changes (and refer to release notes I'm pasting).. There are two upgrade commands Kubuntu suggest (identical commands to Lubuntu I work with, one slightly differs to that in the main release notes, I can provide more if required)  .. `do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE`

Comment: Oh?  Kubuntu-specific?  Dear god.  One of the times `apt` rendered my computer useless was when running KDE Neon and `apt-get install kcalc` resulted in having 2 different versions of QT installed so the GUI no longer worked at all. ...so I hesitate due to past experience... ...Would you mind creating an answer with those steps you're referring to?

Comment: It's only the `-f` part that is specific; ie. if you are performing the upgrade and your screensaver kicks in session maybe lost; the default tool assumes no screensaver (and if GUI GTK+3) so the 'DistUpgradeViewKDE' tells it you are using Qt instead, as Lubuntu (LXQt or Qt5), Kubuntu (KDE with Qt5 & KF5) or for next upgrade, Ubuntu Studio (KDE/Qt5 but not KF5) ... If you use a text terminal, you can use the server command that works on any Ubuntu *flavor* (ie. no options at all).  The options are more *fail safes*